# Creating a function that accepts an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write a function that  accepts an array of numbers and makes a new array of only the first and last elements of the given array.

I can't figure out how to get a function to work with my current code.

```js
var firstLast = [5, 10 ,15 ,20, 25, 30, 40];

firstLast.splice(1, firstLast.length - 2);

console.log(firstLast);
```

I want to have it so that when I call the function, I can put the array of numbers as the parameter.

Comment: What is the problem with this?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect you to explain what your actual _problem_ is (and show us what you tried already), and not just tell us about what the _plan_ is …

Comment: Since your code is working, just wrap it in a function: `function firstLast(arr) { arr.splice(1, arr.length - 2); return arr; }`

Comment: Start by wrapping your code inside a function.

Comment: or a variable? 
const finalArr = firstLast.splice(1, firstLast.length - 2);

Comment: `.splice` modifies the original array. look at `.slice` instead. What if the array is empty or only contains one element? What should be the result then?

Answer (score 0):

> and makes a new array of only the first and last elements of the given array

First of all, `array.splice()` would be the wrong function to use. It modifies the original array, not create a new one. What you need to do is create a new array, then add the first and last items of the original array, literally.

```
const newArray = [firstLast[0], firstLast[firstLast.length - 1]]
```

The first item is always at index `0`. The last item is always at index `length - 1`.

Comment: What if the array is empty or only contains one element? What should the result be then?

Comment: @user633183 That's up to the OP to decide. If it is indeed empty, both will be `undefined` with my answer. If it's a single item, both values are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous function for a one liner (with added checks):

```js
var arr = [5, 10 ,15 ,20, 25, 30, 40];

const getFirstLast = arr => arr && arr.length > 1 ? [arr[0], arr[arr.length - 1]] : arr
console.log(getFirstLast(arr));
```

or just a normal function:

```js
var arr = [5, 10 ,15 ,20, 25, 30, 40];

function getFirstLast(arr) {
  return arr && arr.length > 1
    ? [arr[0], arr[arr.length - 1]]
    : arr 
}

console.log(getFirstLast(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Splice mutates original array, you can simply create a generic function which takes only first and last value

```js
var firstLast = [5, 10 ,15 ,20, 25, 30, 40];

const firstAndLast = (arr) => {
  return Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length > 1 ? [arr[0], arr[arr.length-1]] : arr
}

console.log(firstAndLast(firstLast));
console.log(firstAndLast([1]));
console.log(firstAndLast([1,2,3]));
console.log(firstAndLast());
```